# Reference to forcing with a sigma ideal $\cong$ Cohen forcing

Tags: set-theory, ho.history-overview

This is a historical question: Who was the first person to notice the following?

If $V \models \kappa$ is measurable and $P$ adds $\kappa$ Cohen reals, then in $V^P$, letting $\hat{I}$ to be the ideal generated by a normal prime ideal $I$ over $\kappa$, forcing with $\hat{I}$ is equivalent to adding $|2^{\kappa}|^V$ Cohen reals.

I always thought this was due to Prikry but I cannot find this in his thesis.

Comment: Just curious, where did you first learn about this result?  A book of Fremlin maybe?

Comment: I learned this fact from Kunen. He thinks this may have been known in the 1960s but doesn't remember seeing this in print. Fremlin's book does have this theorem without any attribution (Measure theory, vol. 5 part II, 555G). I also asked Kanamori, Prikry and Solovay but they didn't recall any reference either.

Comment: As you know this fact follows easily from Foreman's Duality Theorem.  My hunch is that Foreman came up with a unification of various folklore arguments about induced ideals that had been floating around since forever.

Comment: What about Solovay's argument for RVM cardinals? Does his proof easily translate to show the claim about adding measurable-many Cohen reals?

Comment: Yes, this is how Kunen proved it. There is a sketch (Lemma 3.2) here: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~akumar/IND_IDEALS.pdf

Comment: Solovay's paper has a more general theorem: If $\kappa$ is real valued measurable then it remains so after adding any number of random reals. He writes "Originally, we only proved Theorem 7 for measurable $\kappa$. Ken Kunen observed that our proof gives the following more general result." I don't see how to get this more general version directly via elementary embeddings. Do you see a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Yes I think so.  Apply Duality to the generic embedding coming from the RVM ideal.  The quotient is a measure algebra by general facts about factoring measure algebras.

Comment: Ok. Can you give me a reference to Foreman's duality theorem?

Comment: Theorem 17 here: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3038554